# After AndroidX migration AndroidTestCase, AndroidJUnit4 & InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext are depricated

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx

After AndroidX migration all my Android tests which extends `AndroidTestCase` stopped working.
I have decided to use `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` instead but this is also deprecated, even `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` is also deprecated.
I want to know right way of updating my tests with out deprecated stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> all my Android tests which extends AndroidTestCase stopped working

`AndroidTestCase` was deprecated [three years ago](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase) with the release of Android 7.0.

> I have decided to use @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) instead but this is also deprecated

Use `androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4`.

> even InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext() is also deprecated

If you are using `androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry`, call `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Additionally I had to use
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1" in my build.gradle for androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4 to work

Comment: So which Context return ApplicationProvider ?

Comment: @UserOne: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: Based on this 《getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().》 ApplicationsProvider also return the App Context under Test

Comment: @UserOne: Ah, I see. Yes, [`ApplicationProvider` has a static `getApplicationContext()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider) that you can use to get the `Application` singleton for the code under test. I was focused more on modifying the code from the question.

Comment: Ok no problems, we can use it too sometime

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your build.gradle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
```

[image]

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnit4